# Undocumented CSS Property

Tags: css, properties

I've been working on some CSS based on a template. Not my choice, but it's what I've got.

In the process of cleaning the CSS up (someone used a CSS prettifier to columnize it, making it a major PITA to write), I've come across an entirely unexplained CSS property: `nowhitespace`.

In the document I have, it appears as `nowhitespace: afterproperty;`, and often is repeated multiple times in a single rule. After trawling the web, I've found this mysterious property cropping up in stylesheets left and right, but never with a single bit of explanation as to what it does, or what the author thinks it does.

So, I'm appealing to you, Stackoverflow community, to please explain the origin of this property that, as far as I can tell, does absolutely nothing and is recognized by no known browser.

Here's a snippet from the document I have, after prettifying:

```
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited {
  /* grouping these selectors makes sure that your links
     retain their button look even after being visited */
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
  nowhitespace: afterproperty;
  nowhitespace: afterproperty;
  nowhitespace: afterproperty;
  nowhitespace: afterproperty;
  nowhitespace: afterproperty;
  nowhitespace: afterproperty;
  display: block; /* this gives the link block properties
    causing it to fill the whole LI containing it. This
    causes the entire area to react to a mouse click. */
  width: 160px; /*this width makes the entire button
    clickable for IE6. If you don't need to support IE6,
    it can be removed. Calculate the proper width by
    subtracting the padding on this link from the width
    of your sidebar container. */
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #C6D580;
}
```

After searching for the text of the comments, I believe the origin of this CSS template to be a generic DreamWeaver template. [Here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing_new_css_layouts.html#a). I wonder where my particular version came from.

Comment: Who wrote that CSS code?

Comment: "*After trawling the web, I've found this mysterious property cropping up in stylesheets left and right*" - please provide links to said stylesheets.

Comment: There is no need to create tags for ``nowhitespace``  ``afterproperty`` as they are much too specific.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - [Lines 203-205.](https://gist.github.com/1630045) That's one. I have a feeling this isn't CSS, but some kind of parsing instruction.

Comment: I found this: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/nowhitespace Which is related to ConTeXt, a TeX processor. So my thought is it may have something to do with a presentation view partially supporting CSS and outputting to a TeX view (maybe PDF or whatnot?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nowhitespace` isn't a valid CSS property in any of the main browsers. If you try it you'll get an error or warning in that browser's console window.

Firefox gives me this error when I try it in jsfiddle:

> Timestamp: 2012-09-09 01:06:10
>
> Warning: Unknown property 'nowhitespace'.  Declaration dropped.
>
> Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
>   Line: 14

When I google it I find a few stylesheets using the name, but as a class name, not as a property. It's possible someone copied it without knowing what it was (i.e. cargo-cult programming).

Comment: See [lines 203-205](https://gist.github.com/1630045). There seems to be others, if you search the entire `nowhitespace: afterproperty;` with Google.

Comment: [Here's another.](http://code.google.com/p/lightblog/source/browse/trunk/admin/style/new/create.css?r=562&spec=svn564#36)

Comment: I've found even more, as well. Point is, they're out there in the wild. After searching turned up no explanations, I figured cargo-cult programming, and asked this question to get the final word and perhaps even an originating source for this sillyness.

Comment: I'd like to clarify, I already knew this was not a valid property.

Answer (score 4):

This code creeps into stylesheets processed through the tool '[ProCSSor](http://procssor.com/)'.

I suspect it's a bit of internal code determining how the CSS should be rewritten, as a plain English reading of "no white space after property" appears to refer to the formatting of a property in the stylesheet, rather that the rendering of an element on a webpage.

Therefore I'd suggest this is a bug in the software. I've [reported it on their Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/plechem/status/322286889530953728), so hopefully it'll be resolved in a future release.